# How do I display specific data from json that fulfill a condition?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I'm trying to display particular data for a specific name menu.
For example : `/menu/${menuId}/{row.name}` (here for instance menuId= "Menu1" and row.name= "Pea Soup"). I want to get all the information ( in `<div>` or `<p>` from my match.json that corresponds to Pea Soup for example when I'm clicking on "Pea Soup".

```
export default function MenuDisplay() {
  const { menuId } = useParams();
  const { match } = JsonData;

  const matchData = match.find((el) => el._id_menu === menuId)?._ids ?? [];

  const data = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Name",
        accessor: (row) => (
          <Link to={{ pathname: `/menu/${menuId}/${row.name}` }}>
            {row.name}
          </Link>
        )
      }, ...
```

I'm able to display all the content of the match.json but not  for a specific menu selection...

Here is the code : [sandbox_link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redirection-link-not-working-and-applying-filters-on-table-forked-iz8498?file=/src/MenuDisplay.jsx)

Comment: I've just checked your sandbox and it seems to work fine when viewing the url with the menu id https://59vxny.csb.app/menu/Menu1 so confused as to what the problem is here, are you able to be a bit more specific

Comment: Hi, when you select "Menu1" and click on Pea Soup, I want to be redirected to a new page that contains other info that are contained in match.json for this sepcific selection (i.e Pea Soup)

Comment: I can display all infomartion that I need (name, description...) from the json but not for one particular menu selection (i.e pea Soup) . And if you click on Pea Soup (/menu/Menu1/PeaSoup), you get 'Page not found' . This page doesn't exist yet and I don't know how to display my info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build out another page like we did for the `MenuDisplay` table page. Use the `menuId` and the new `itemId` from the route params to again search/find the `matches.json` data.

Example:

```
function MenuDisplay() {
  const { menuId, itemId } = useParams();
  const { match } = JsonData;

  const matchData = match.find((el) => el._id_menu === menuId)?._ids ?? [];
  const item = matchData.find((el) => el._id === itemId);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Menu Item</h1>
      <div>
        <p>Name: {item.name}</p>
        <p>Description: {item.description}</p>
        <p>Dishes: {Object.values(item.dishes[0]).join(", ")}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Fix the link to use the item id of the menu item being linked to.

```
accessor: (row) => (
  <Link to={{ pathname: `/menu/${menuId}/${row._id}` }}>
    {row.name}
  </Link>
)
```

Add a route to handle rendering this new `MenuItemDisplay` component.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/menu" element={<Display />} />
  <Route path="/menu/:menuId" element={<MenuDisplay />} />
  <Route path="/menu/:menuId/:itemId" element={<MenuItemDisplay />} />
  <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit react-how-do-i-display-specific-data-from-json-that-fullfill-a-condition]

Comment: hi, Oh I thought that I can do MenuItemDisplay in MenuDisplay, not creating a new component

Comment: @Zokulko Again, you *could* try to make a single component do everything, but this sort of defeats the point of React and using these routes, i.e. breaking your UI down into smaller and simpler units of code. If you want `MenuDisplay` to also handle and render specific item details then there's no point in using the `Link`, just use some local state and apply some conditional rendering to render either the table or the specific item's details. It's doable, but I don't advocate for it.